# How do I find the equation from this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this thing in a video game that I'd like to optimize using math instead of trying random combinations. In every game loop, the game calculates the new value ("newRotorEnergy" in the equations below) using the old value ("oldRotorEnergy"). *How do I convert this into an equation where I can plug in the elapsed loops (time)?*

> $newRotorEnergy = oldRotorEnergy+liftTorque-\frac{oldRotorEnergy}{4000*rotorMass}-\frac{rotorMass}{10}-inductionTorque$
>
> $inductionTorque = \frac{coilSize*inductorDragCoefficient*oldRotorEnergy}{bladeSurfaceArea*rotorMass}$

These equations do not vary with time:

> liftTorque = 10*(((bladeSurfaceArea*max(0,steamIntake-usableSteam))/floor(steamIntake/25))+useableSteam)
>
> useableSteam = 25*bladeSurfaceArea

**Edit 2:** rotorMass, steamIntake, useableSteam, coilSize, inductorDragCoefficient, and bladeSurfaceArea will all be constant and positive throughout each iteration.

**Edit 3:** Here's a graph of what I get when I calculate rotorEnergy by going step by step using a particular combination of values (that I happen to play with). The vertical axis is the rotorSpeed (which is easy to calculate using rotorEnergy and rotorMass), and the horizontal is the number of iterations divided by 1200 (real life minutes).

[image]

And here's another example of other possible values (over 60 minutes):

[image]

**Edit:** "rotorEnergy" starts at 0 in the game (since you don't want people to create free energy), but I don't think that's important.

Comment: Where do you want to plug in the elapsed loops, and what does it need to do to the equation?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll learn MathJax in a few minutes but for now I converted to plain text.
With each loop iteration it calculates "newRotorEnergy" (which is the value I want) using "oldRotorEnergy" (the value of "newRotorEnergy" last iteration). Oh and it starts at 0.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. Are you looking for "newRotorEnergy" to be produced as some function of n, where n is the loop you are on?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for understanding, I know that was pretty confusing.

Comment: @user165680: The big question here is, can any of the of the primitive variables change from cycle to cycle? By the primitive variables, I mean (in order given in the code) rS, bSA, nRB, sI, cS, iDC, rE, and rM. If the answer is not "no, all of them are constant", then we're going to have a tough time unless we can precisely describe how they change. But let us know, there could be a hack anyway.

Comment: Well in the game all are constant except for steamIn which can change, but my goal is to find the optimal values so my guess is that steamIn will be a constant as well. I didn't provide the equation I'm trying to optimize, but it's just simple math once I know the rotorSpeed, inductionTorque, and two other variables. Also I fixed an issue in the rE equation that will definately make it easier to understand. Unimportant but: when I was trying different combinations, I noticed that there were two different steamIn values that produced a high output value. I'm excited to see the math behind it!

Comment: @ Eric Stucky: Thanks for the reply. I added in a graph of one possible combination of values.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "trying to optimize" ? Are you trying to speed it up?

Comment: @Winther: Sorry for the confusion, I haven't posted the equation I'm trying to optimize, but I think it's really simple once I know rotorEnergy and some other variables I didn't mention. I need to know what the rotorEnergy value will be at infinite time, since some input values will take longer to increase rotorEnergy, but may produce a greater value in the end. And I'm not concerned about the time to reach it's peak since I could play other aspects of the game while waiting, and some players play the game on a persistent game world where they may leave for a week so time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_n$ by rotor energy at step $n$ (read: $R_n$ is $\text{newRotorEnergy}$ and $R_{n-1}$ is $\text{oldRotorEnergy}$ ). Then we can define the following recurence relation:

$$R_{n} = R_{n-1}a + b$$

where $$b = -\text{rotorMass}/10 + \text{liftTorque}$$ and $$a = 1 - \frac{1}{4000\text{rotorMass}} - \text{inductionTorque}$$ where $\text{inductionTorque}$ is the equation you gave but without the factor $\text{oldRotorEnergy}$.

If I understand you correctly then all the terms in $a$ and $b$ are constant and we can then easily solve for $R_n$ to get

$$R_n = \frac{b(a^n-1)}{a-1} + C a^n$$

for some constant $C$ which is determined by the initial conditions. Since $R_0 = 0$ we get

$$R_n = \frac{b(a^n-1)}{a-1}$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite seem to get that equation to match up with mine (that matches the game), I'm probably not explaining something right. Here are the values I used to generate the first graph: liftTorque=20000,rotorMass=960,coilSize=37,inductorD.C.=0.3,bladeS.A.=84. And here are some data points in shown in the graph, as (elapsed loops, rotorEnergy):(0,0),(6000,81236465),(12000,116747795),(24000,139056818),(36000,143319789)

Comment: @user165680 I have fixed the equation, I had a mistake in my solution. The one I have now agrees with your values (for which $a=0.999862$ and $b=19904$)